# cleaning up table data from a webscraper

Tags: python, numpy, selenium, dictionary

I have a webscraper that pulls table data and sometimes it's uneven in the data it gets, it pulls the data into a table like so

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common import exceptions

url5001= "https://matrix.heartlandmls.com/Matrix/Public/Portal.aspx?L=1&k=990316X949Z&p=DE-77667588-490"                                                                          
new_set5001 = []
ignored_exceptions = [exceptions.NoSuchElementException, exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException, exceptions.WebDriverException]
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url5001)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/form/div[3]/div/div/div[5]/div[3]/span[2]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/span/a").click()
time.sleep(5)
# 500 total listings on this site but the scraper has some behavior i can't explain
while True:
    if len(new_set5001)>=570:
        print('done')
        break
    else:
        try:
            new_set5001.append(driver.find_element_by_id("wrapperTable").text)
            WebDriverWait(driver, 20, ignored_exceptions=ignored_exceptions).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/form/div[3]/div/div/div[5]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/span/ul/li[2]/a"))).click()
        except (exceptions.NoSuchElementException, exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException) as err:
            time.sleep(15)
```

the first entry looks like this:

```
new_set5001[0]=
"About 403 W Main Street, Cleveland, MO 64734\nDirections:From Kansas City-South to Cleveland Mo., D-Highway & Y-Highway turn west onto Main St., go through the the 4 way stop. home is on the south side (left). From Kansas us 69 Highway & 247th St. exit, east to Cleveland to the house on the south side.\nGeneral Description\nMLS Number\n2225041\nCounty\nCass\nCity\nCleveland\nSub Div\nCleveland\nType\nSingle Family\nFloor Plan Description\nRanch\nBdrms\n3\nBaths Full\n1\nBaths Half\n1\nAge Description\n101 Years/More\nYear Built\n1900\nSqft Main\n1307\nSQFT MAIN SOURCE\nPublic Record\nBelow Grade Finished Sq Ft\n0\nBelow Grade Finished Sq Ft Source\nPublic Record\nSqft\n1307\nLot Size\n100' X 172'\nSchool District\nCass-Midway\nS Terms\nCash\nInterior Features\nFireplace?\nY\nFireplace Description\nLiving Room\nBasement\nN\nBasement Description\nCrawl Space\nDining Area Description\nEat-In Kitchen\nUtility Room\nOff The Kitchen\nInterior Features\nFixer Up, Partial Carpeting\nExterior / Construction\nGarage/Parking?\nN\nConstruction\nBrick Trim, Frame\nArchitecture\nOther\nRoof\nComposition\nLot Description\nCity Lot\nIn Floodplain\nNo\nInside City Limits\nYes\nStreet Maintenance\nPaved\nExterior Features\nFixer Up\nUtility Information\nCentral Air\nN\nHeat\nNatural Gas\nCool\nNone\nWater\nCity/Public\nSewer\nCity/Public\nFinancial Information\nS Terms\nCash\nHoa Amount\n$0\nTax\n$1,005\nSpecial Tax\n$0\nTotal Tax\n$1,005\nType Of Ownership\nPrivate\nWill Sell\nCash, Conventional"
```

next I split the lines

```
new_set5001a = []
for i in range(len(new_set5001)):
    new_set5001a.append(new_set5001[i].splitlines())
#this yields a nested list
# passed these to a list of arrays for operations

np_arrays = []
for array in new_set5001a:
    np_arrays.append(np.array(array))
```

the first array looks like this

```
array(['About 403 W Main Street, Cleveland, MO 64734',
       'Directions:From Kansas City-South to Cleveland Mo., D-Highway & Y-Highway turn west onto Main St., go through the the 4 way stop. home is on the south side (left). From Kansas us 69 Highway & 247th St. exit, east to Cleveland to the house on the south side.',
       'General Description', 'MLS Number', '2225041', 'County', 'Cass',
       'City', 'Cleveland', 'Sub Div', 'Cleveland', 'Type',
       'Single Family', 'Floor Plan Description', 'Ranch', 'Bdrms', '3',
       'Baths Full', '1', 'Baths Half', '1', 'Age Description',
       '101 Years/More', 'Year Built', '1900', 'Sqft Main', '1307',
       'SQFT MAIN SOURCE', 'Public Record', 'Below Grade Finished Sq Ft',
       '0', 'Below Grade Finished Sq Ft Source', 'Public Record', 'Sqft',
       '1307', 'Lot Size', "100' X 172'", 'School District',
       'Cass-Midway', 'S Terms', 'Cash', 'Interior Features',
       'Fireplace?', 'Y', 'Fireplace Description', 'Living Room',
       'Basement', 'N', 'Basement Description', 'Crawl Space',
       'Dining Area Description', 'Eat-In Kitchen', 'Utility Room',
       'Off The Kitchen', 'Interior Features',
       'Fixer Up, Partial Carpeting', 'Exterior / Construction',
       'Garage/Parking?', 'N', 'Construction', 'Brick Trim, Frame',
       'Architecture', 'Other', 'Roof', 'Composition', 'Lot Description',
       'City Lot', 'In Floodplain', 'No', 'Inside City Limits', 'Yes',
       'Street Maintenance', 'Paved', 'Exterior Features', 'Fixer Up',
       'Utility Information', 'Central Air', 'N', 'Heat', 'Natural Gas',
       'Cool', 'None', 'Water', 'City/Public', 'Sewer', 'City/Public',
       'Financial Information', 'S Terms', 'Cash', 'Hoa Amount', '$0',
       'Tax', '$1,005', 'Special Tax', '$0', 'Total Tax', '$1,005',
       'Type Of Ownership', 'Private', 'Will Sell', 'Cash, Conventional'],
      dtype='<U257')
```

now working with the first array to expand out from there I have used this function, and it's almost there, ultimately I would prefer a list of key value pairs, not just a dictionary as it is now

```
def clean_data(arr, feature_list):
    '''
     I can see now that I did not use the list new as planned
     try and except is used because not all the listings will have all of the
     keys i need
    '''
    new = []

    for val in feature_list:
        try:
            # y finds the index of the next value which is what is wanted
            # z builds the array getting the value
            # z1 returns only that value, maybe a cleaner way to do this?
            y = (np.argwhere(arr==val)+1).flatten()
            z = np.where(arr==val, arr[y], None)
            z1 = z[z!=None][0]
            new.append(z1)
        except:
            new.append(None)
    return dict(zip(feature_list, new))

feature_list = ['MLS Number','County', 'City', 'Sub Div', 'Type',
        'Floor Plan Description', 'Bdrms',
       'Baths Full', 'Baths Half','Year Built', 'Sqft Main', 
       'SQFT MAIN SOURCE', 'Below Grade Finished Sq Ft',
       'Below Grade Finished Sq Ft Source', 'Lot Size', 'School District',
       'Fireplace?', 'Fireplace Description',
       'Basement', 'Basement Description',
       'Garage/Parking?', 'Construction', 
       'Architecture', 'Roof',  'Lot Description',
      'In Floodplain', 'Inside City Limits', 
       'Street Maintenance','Central Air', 'Heat', 
       'Cool', 'Water','Sewer']

clean_data(np_arrays[0], feature_list)
{'MLS Number': '2225041',
 'County': 'Cass',
 'City': 'Cleveland',
 'Sub Div': 'Cleveland',
 'Type': 'Single Family',
 'Floor Plan Description': 'Ranch',
 'Bdrms': '3',
 'Baths Full': '1',
 'Baths Half': '1',
 'Year Built': '1900',
 'Sqft Main': '1307',
 'SQFT MAIN SOURCE': 'Public Record',
 'Below Grade Finished Sq Ft': '0',
 'Below Grade Finished Sq Ft Source': 'Public Record',
 'Lot Size': "100' X 172'",
 'School District': 'Cass-Midway',
 'Fireplace?': 'Y',
 'Fireplace Description': 'Living Room',
 'Basement': 'N',
 'Basement Description': 'Crawl Space',
 'Garage/Parking?': 'N',
 'Construction': 'Brick Trim, Frame',
 'Architecture': 'Other',
 'Roof': 'Composition',
 'Lot Description': 'City Lot',
 'In Floodplain': 'No',
 'Inside City Limits': 'Yes',
 'Street Maintenance': 'Paved',
 'Central Air': 'N',
 'Heat': 'Natural Gas',
 'Cool': 'None',
 'Water': 'City/Public',
 'Sewer': 'City/Public'}
```

this is the direction I want to go because it takes care of my uneven dataset and the None's are important features too (shows up more with the next listing, not on this listing)

## however, the goal is to loop through and return a table of dictionaries for ease of use

I have the following code set up for the first 2 entries and I can see what it is doing incorrectly, in that it's returning everything as dictionary but I do not know how to proceed from here, I tried similar code to my function and it only returned the first entry

```
new2 = []
for i in range(len(new_set5001a)):
    x = np_arrays[i]
    for val in feature_list:
        try:
            y = (np.argwhere(x==val)+1).flatten()
            z = np.where(x==val, x[y], None)
            z1 = z[z!=None][0]
            new2.append({val:z1})
        except:
            new2.append({val:None})
```

this does return all of the data, but the formatting is incorrect
returns

```
[{'MLS Number': '2225041'},
 {'County': 'Cass'},
 {'City': 'Cleveland'},
 {'Sub Div': 'Cleveland'},
 {'Type': 'Single Family'},
 {'Floor Plan Description': 'Ranch'},
 {'Bdrms': '3'},
 {'Baths Full': '1'},
 {'Baths Half': '1'},
 {'Year Built': '1900'},
 {'Sqft Main': '1307'},
 {'SQFT MAIN SOURCE': 'Public Record'},
 {'Below Grade Finished Sq Ft': '0'},
 {'Below Grade Finished Sq Ft Source': 'Public Record'},
 {'Lot Size': "100' X 172'"},
 {'School District': 'Cass-Midway'},
 {'Fireplace?': 'Y'},
 {'Fireplace Description': 'Living Room'},
 {'Basement': 'N'},
 {'Basement Description': 'Crawl Space'},
 {'Garage/Parking?': 'N'},
 {'Construction': 'Brick Trim, Frame'},
 {'Architecture': 'Other'},
 {'Roof': 'Composition'},
 {'Lot Description': 'City Lot'},
 {'In Floodplain': 'No'},
 {'Inside City Limits': 'Yes'},
 {'Street Maintenance': 'Paved'},
 {'Central Air': 'N'},
 {'Heat': 'Natural Gas'},
 {'Cool': 'None'},
 {'Water': 'City/Public'},
 {'Sewer': 'City/Public'},
 {'MLS Number': '2212446'},
 {'County': 'Cass'},
 {'City': 'Garden City'},
 {'Sub Div': 'Hedge Trails'},
 {'Type': 'Single Family'},
 {'Floor Plan Description': 'Ranch'},
 {'Bdrms': '2'},
 {'Baths Full': '1'},
 {'Baths Half': '0'},
 {'Year Built': '1974'},
 {'Sqft Main': '960'},
 {'SQFT MAIN SOURCE': 'Public Record'},
 {'Below Grade Finished Sq Ft': '0'},
 {'Below Grade Finished Sq Ft Source': 'Public Record'},
 {'Lot Size': '78x120'},
 {'School District': 'Sherwood'},
 {'Fireplace?': 'N'},
 {'Fireplace Description': None},
 {'Basement': 'N'},
 {'Basement Description': 'Crawl Space'},
 {'Garage/Parking?': 'Y'},
 {'Construction': 'Frame, Vinyl Siding'},
 {'Architecture': 'Traditional'},
 {'Roof': 'Composition'},
 {'Lot Description': 'City Lot, Corner Lot'},
 {'In Floodplain': 'No'},
 {'Inside City Limits': None},
 {'Street Maintenance': None},
 {'Central Air': 'Y'},
 {'Heat': 'Forced Air Gas, Natural Gas'},
 {'Cool': 'Central Electric'},
 {'Water': 'City/Public'},
 {'Sewer': 'City/Public'}]
```

I also tried the following but it stopped after the first iteration

```
new2 = []
for i in range(len(new_set5001a)):
    x = np_arrays[i]
    d = []
    for val in feature_list:
        try:
            y = (np.argwhere(x==val)+1).flatten()
            z = np.where(x==val, x[y], None)
            z1 = z[z!=None][0]
            new2.append(z1)
        except:
            new2.append(None)
    d = dict(zip(feature_list, new2))
# returns
{'MLS Number': '2225041',
 'County': 'Cass',
 'City': 'Cleveland',
 'Sub Div': 'Cleveland',
 'Type': 'Single Family',
 'Floor Plan Description': 'Ranch',
 'Bdrms': '3',
 'Baths Full': '1',
 'Baths Half': '1',
 'Year Built': '1900',
 'Sqft Main': '1307',
 'SQFT MAIN SOURCE': 'Public Record',
 'Below Grade Finished Sq Ft': '0',
 'Below Grade Finished Sq Ft Source': 'Public Record',
 'Lot Size': "100' X 172'",
 'School District': 'Cass-Midway',
 'Fireplace?': 'Y',
 'Fireplace Description': 'Living Room',
 'Basement': 'N',
 'Basement Description': 'Crawl Space',
 'Garage/Parking?': 'N',
 'Construction': 'Brick Trim, Frame',
 'Architecture': 'Other',
 'Roof': 'Composition',
 'Lot Description': 'City Lot',
 'In Floodplain': 'No',
 'Inside City Limits': 'Yes',
 'Street Maintenance': 'Paved',
 'Central Air': 'N',
 'Heat': 'Natural Gas',
 'Cool': 'None',
 'Water': 'City/Public',
 'Sewer': 'City/Public'}
```

I think I am one step, maybe 2 away, but I'm stumped as to the next step

## goal

```
[{'foo':'bar','foo1':'bar1',.....'foo_n': 'bar_n'}, {'foo':'bar','foo1':'bar1',.....'foo_n': 'bar_n'}]
```

actual output so far

```
{'foo':'bar'},{'foo1':'bar1'},{'foo_n': 'bar_n'},{'foo':'bar'},....}
```

second attempt output

```
{'foo':'bar',......,'foo_n': 'bar_n'}
```

one small thing I've noticed with the behavior of this scraper.. it grabs duplicate entries from time to time, so I just added roughly 70 extras at the end just in case, not a major deal, but i do not know why it behaves like that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it didn't hit me, but editing the question it hit me, just instantiate a new empty list, iterate over it and call the original function

```
new2 = []
for i in range(len(np_arrays)):
    new2.append(clean_data(np_arrays[i], feature_list))
print(new2)
```

[{'MLS Number': '2212446', 'County': 'Cass', 'City': 'Garden City', 'Sub Div': 'Hedge Trails', 'Type': 'Single Family', 'Floor Plan Description': 'Ranch', 'Bdrms': '2', 'Baths Full': '1', 'Baths Half': '0', 'Year Built': '1974', 'Sqft Main': '960', 'SQFT MAIN SOURCE': 'Public Record', 'Below Grade Finished Sq Ft': '0', 'Below Grade Finished Sq Ft Source': 'Public Record', 'Lot Size': '78x120', 'School District': 'Sherwood', 'Fireplace?': 'N', 'Fireplace Description': None, 'Basement': 'N', 'Basement Description': 'Crawl Space', 'Garage/Parking?': 'Y', 'Construction': 'Frame, Vinyl Siding', 'Architecture': 'Traditional', 'Roof': 'Composition', 'Lot Description': 'City Lot, Corner Lot', 'In Floodplain': 'No', 'Inside City Limits': None, 'Street Maintenance': None, 'Central Air': 'Y', 'Heat': 'Forced Air Gas, Natural Gas', 'Cool': 'Central Electric', 'Water': 'City/Public', 'Sewer': 'City/Public'}, {'MLS Number': '2230744', 'County': 'Cass', 'City': 'Garden City', 'Sub Div': 'Garden West', 'Type': 'Single Family', 'Floor Plan Description': '2 Stories', 'Bdrms': '3', 'Baths Full': '2', 'Baths Half': '0', 'Year Built': None, 'Sqft Main': '1386', 'SQFT MAIN SOURCE': 'Public Record', 'Below Grade Finished Sq Ft': '0', 'Below Grade Finished Sq Ft Source': 'Public Record', 'Lot Size': '1', 'School District': 'Sherwood', 'Fireplace?': 'N', 'Fireplace Description': None, 'Basement': 'Y', 'Basement Description': 'Concrete', 'Garage/Parking?': 'Y', 'Construction': 'Other', 'Architecture': None, 'Roof': 'Composition', 'Lot Description': None, 'In Floodplain': 'No', 'Inside City Limits': None, 'Street Maintenance': None, 'Central Air': 'Y', 'Heat': 'Central Electric', 'Cool': 'Central Electric', 'Water': 'City/Public', 'Sewer': 'City/Public'}]

so just some sanity checks

```
in:  len(new2)
out: 2
in:  len(new2[0])
out: 34
in:  len(new2[1])
out: 34
```